# How to show two sections and rows in Collectionview in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, sections

I have added one collection view with constraints

```
leading = 10, trailing = 10 top = 10 height = 200
```

I have two arrays called **oldArray and newArray**.. my requirement is.. if I come from isEdit initially I need to show the only oldArray in section 0 and if add new images(newArray) then I need to show them in section 1.. but I am not able to add newArray images in section 1.. with my below code newly added images also adding in section 0..

total code for two arrays and collectionview:

```
 struct ImagesModel{

public var image : String?

init(image: String?) {
    self.image = image
}
}


import UIKit

class BidPlaceVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
var oldArray = [ImagesModel]()

var newArray = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var filesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4.1
    let height = width*1.1
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 100)
    self.filesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    
    filesCollectionView.reloadData()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if isEdit{
    if section == 0{
        return  oldArray.count
    }
    else{
        return  self.newArray.count
    }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0{
             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilesCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? FilesCollectionCell

            let img =  self.oldArray[indexPath.item].image
            cell?.imgView.getImage(withUrl: img, placeHolder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "home"), imgContentMode: .scaleAspectFill)
                return cell!

        }
        else{
             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilesCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? FilesCollectionCell

            cell?.imgView.image = self.newArray[indexPath.item]
          
            return cell!
        }

    }




func uploadServiceCall() {
  
    var imgData = [Data]()
    for image in self.newArray {
        imgData.append(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!)
    }
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.uploadMultipleImagesWithParam(url: CommonUrl.place_bid, imagesData: imgData, imageKey: "files", parameters: param, completionHandler: {(responseData) in
       
        
        if let result = responseData.dict?["result"] as? NSDictionary{
            
            if message == "Success"{
                
                var filesArray = result["files_uploaded"] as? String
                self.oldArray.append(ImagesModel(image: filesArray, id: 0))
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.filesCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
}

@IBAction func submitBitBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    uploadServiceCall()
}
```

o/p.. here newly added images also adding in section 0, why?

how to add newly added images in section 1, please do help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to specify the number of sections is missing (the default is 1)

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return newArray.isEmpty ? 1 : 2
}
```